# How to draw an ellipse/circle over QGraphicsScene in a QGraphicsView

Tags: qt, qt4, qgraphicsview, qpainter

I have a QGraphicsView with a QGraphicsScene. That QGraphicsScene contains a QPixmap. It is possible to drag the scene. On top of that scene I have a HUD with QLabels, QPushButtons and other stuff. When I drag the scene around, the HUD elements never change their position. So far it works all perfect. But now I need to add a new element to this HUD, an ellipse/circle. 
But all the stuff I tried, isn't working properly. 
The problem, if you are over that circle, with the mouse, it must be still possible to grab and drag the scene. So I need only a visible circle, that is completely ignored by the mouse or any other action. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If setting the circle widget to disabled using `setEnabled(false)` doesn't give you the desired effect, try calling `setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents, true)` on it.